# LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() returning POSITION_NONE

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to do something like this:

```
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager recyclerManager;
//set items....
recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
int itemPosition = recyclerManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); //returns -1
```

But there are clearly new items on the screen. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()), I see this:

> Returns the adapter position of the first visible view. This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass.

So I am thinking that the layout pass is not done yet. But I don't know how to ensure that it is done before I call this method. I even tried this:

```
if (!isInLayout()) {
    recyclerManager.requestLayout();
}
```

before calling the method, but that did not help. Thanks for any help.

Comment: is there any item included in the adapter? did you assign the adapter to the RecyclerVIew ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the problem is that a layout pass has not yet occurred, and that is why you are getting `POSITION_NONE`.

Simply doing a check like `if (!isInLayout())` will not work, because you will do that check a single time, it will return false, and that's the end of it.

What you really want to do in this scenario is use a [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) to listen for layout events.

For example:

```
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int itemPosition = recyclerManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }
});
```

As an aside, if you are only using `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` when populating your RecyclerView for the first time, you likely don't need it at all. The first visible item will always be 0 unless you are doing something else to scroll the RecyclerView as well.

Comment: Thanks, Tanis! I just tried something similar, and it seemed to work. But not sure if one is preferable to the other: `recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    }
                });`

Comment: Is there a way to write a unit test for findFirstVisibleItemPosition() ?