# endless recyclerview to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need a endless recyclerview to top, like messager apps.

So I add:

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

to start my list in the end.

I add the new values on top:

```
listL.add(0, PostObj);
```

but I can't read the first position on my recyclerview.

findFirstVisibleItemPosition is not getting the first item

```
   private boolean isFirstItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (firstVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

I changed it from my old code that works in a endless recyclerview scroll to bottom. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: can you verify if `recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0` returns true?

Comment: @Yashasvi thank you, I'll check it now. just a second, please!

Comment: maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272178/linearlayoutmanager-findfirstvisibleitemposition-returning-position-none

Comment: @Yashasvi yeah, it is returning true. I'll check. thank you!

Comment: @GabrielaDias check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058676/detect-top-of-reversed-recyclerview) , it may help you

Comment: thank you friends. I changed `recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1` to `1` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a question about same concern.

Please refer [EndlessScrollListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718149/recyclerview-reverse-endless-scrolling/50618951#50618951)